# Deriving the partial chain rule using first principles

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, spherical-coordinates, chain-rule

Can someone derive the chain rule for         ∂/∂x(T) using first principle where T is a function of x(r,θ,φ),y(r,θ,φ),z(r,θ,φ) ?

The equation goes like:

∂T/∂x=∂T/∂r(∂r/∂x)+∂T/∂θ(∂θ/∂x)+∂T/∂φ(∂φ/∂x)

How can you prove it from first principle?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: any mathematician would understand what i have asked for

Comment: See [Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case): you have that $T(x)$ is $T[r(x), \theta(x), \varphi(x)]$.

Comment: thank u so much